# Meteor error: "Tunneling socket could not be established" - SSL issue with properly configured proxy?

Tags: ssl, curl, meteor, proxy, npm

I'm using Meteor on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS behind a corporate proxy, but am unable to apply any updates or even create a Meteor instance. Running meteor update gives me the following:

```
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY
environment variables or see this page for more details:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

This project is already at Meteor 1.4.1.1, the latest release.
=> Errors while upgrading packages:

While downloading autoupdate@1.2.11...:
error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO
139992700094336:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:
```

etc. -- the last error repeats for all other packages.

- I have  set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY with my username and password. These settings seem to work find with everything except Meteor.  For example, APT-GET proxy settings are configured and work fine
- NPM is configured with proxy and https-proxy, is set for ssl-strict=false, and works fine outside of Meteor.  I've also tried setting the register to "http://registry.npmjs.org/" - but no luck for Meteor.
- When I install Meteor, I need to use the '-k' or '--insecure' option on curl, or else I get an SSL error.   With this option (curl -k https://install.meteor.com/ | sh), Meteor installs fine and without any errors

  I've seen several questions around this error, and the fixes work for NPM, etc. outside of Meteor, but with Meteor, I'm still stuck.  Is there a similar '--insecure' option for meteor update?  Or is there a script where I can add a similar option? What mechanism is Meteor actually using to request updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting https_proxy=**http**://{proxy} did the trick for me!

Comment: I can't believe this worked, but I'll be damned if it didn't clear up my issue too! Thanks!